# GLMM for negative values with response variable resulting from meta analysis

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics

I am modeling the effect of turbidity over plankton and the dataset used to is an output of a meta-analysis. I did not manage to model through metafor R package since my model has both a random factor and non-normally distributed data and residuals, so glmm in lmer4 seems to be a way to do so.

I have been trying to fit this glmm model with lme4 package with a dataset that has several negative values at the response variable (yi).

My dataset is composed by ID, the studies identification, yi, the mean effect size, and vi, the variance of effect size.

Here´s the dataset:

| ID | yi | vi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | -0.477468938 | 0.08015310 |
| 11 | -0.461441936 | 0.08202484 |
| 11 | -0.970734913 | 0.17221690 |
| 11 | -1.192061822 | 0.11729728 |
| 11 | -1.257430127 | 0.14515598 |
| 11 | -1.251173875 | 0.11893847 |
| 11 | -0.337834009 | 0.07788831 |
| 11 | -0.324076524 | 0.07979774 |
| 11 | -0.926113496 | 0.16961868 |
| 11 | -1.181103233 | 0.11550005 |
| 11 | -1.207001666 | 0.14200892 |
| 11 | -1.245161394 | 0.11722697 |
| 14 | -2.730634291 | 0.19320455 |
| 14 | -1.960220804 | 0.14803082 |
| 14 | -4.023926827 | 0.30239984 |
| 14 | -2.535567191 | 0.18036376 |
| 14 | -0.501556539 | 0.10314449 |
| 14 | 3.109068530 | 0.22082884 |
| 14 | -3.038293974 | 0.21539038 |
| 14 | -1.960220804 | 0.14803082 |
| 14 | -4.024315970 | 0.30243899 |
| 14 | -2.535567191 | 0.18036376 |
| 14 | 0.352652392 | 0.10155455 |
| 14 | 3.254652363 | 0.23240953 |
| 14 | -4.275494854 | 0.32849820 |
| 14 | -1.960220804 | 0.14803082 |
| 14 | -2.976999453 | 0.21078157 |
| 14 | -2.535567191 | 0.18036376 |
| 14 | -4.687915391 | 0.37470688 |
| 14 | -1.042555053 | 0.11358651 |
| 23 | -0.368518019 | 0.25424392 |
| 23 | 0.249693722 | 0.25194834 |
| 23 | -0.212957809 | 0.25141722 |
| 23 | -0.170091446 | 0.25090410 |
| 23 | -0.318663454 | 0.25317332 |
| 23 | 0.135900077 | 0.25057715 |
| 23 | 0.033761295 | 0.25003562 |
| 23 | -0.151680733 | 0.25071897 |
| 23 | 0.246180932 | 0.25189391 |
| 23 | 0.091117420 | 0.25025945 |
| 23 | -0.560253702 | 0.25980888 |
| 23 | -0.279199121 | 0.25243600 |
| 23 | -0.445612909 | 0.25620534 |
| 23 | -0.111269308 | 0.25038690 |
| 23 | 0.624443402 | 0.26218530 |
| 23 | 0.906015531 | 0.27565200 |
| 23 | 0.781702343 | 0.26909558 |
| 23 | 0.850302595 | 0.27259420 |
| 23 | 0.789749589 | 0.26949076 |
| 23 | 0.698798853 | 0.26525999 |
| 23 | 1.185076393 | 0.29388769 |
| 23 | -0.465113178 | 0.25676032 |
| 23 | 0.114825733 | 0.25041203 |
| 23 | 0.171411553 | 0.25091819 |
| 23 | 0.349526854 | 0.25381778 |
| 23 | -0.152097262 | 0.25072292 |
| 23 | -0.221230141 | 0.25152946 |
| 23 | -0.115908151 | 0.25041983 |
| 23 | 0.403313677 | 0.27327921 |
| 23 | 0.463686055 | 0.27502397 |
| 23 | 0.299395374 | 0.27084506 |
| 23 | 0.518369606 | 0.27681404 |
| 23 | 0.501452278 | 0.27623896 |
| 23 | 0.339143376 | 0.27169108 |
| 23 | -0.213932212 | 0.26938271 |
| 23 | 0.381423048 | 0.27270659 |
| 23 | 0.559985394 | 0.27830993 |
| 23 | 0.304691853 | 0.27095171 |
| 23 | 0.453787153 | 0.27472124 |
| 23 | 0.454393541 | 0.27473959 |
| 23 | 0.289461860 | 0.27065008 |
| 23 | 0.055337067 | 0.26795922 |
| 23 | 0.003912069 | 0.26785765 |
| 23 | 0.169141191 | 0.26881077 |
| 23 | -0.207908172 | 0.26929800 |
| 23 | 0.132929699 | 0.26844615 |
| 23 | 0.002410189 | 0.26785734 |
| 23 | 0.014924987 | 0.26786457 |
| 23 | -0.257782291 | 0.27007220 |
| 23 | -0.810490125 | 0.28975362 |
| 23 | -0.899968353 | 0.29485524 |
| 23 | -0.563292728 | 0.27843377 |
| 23 | -0.814838168 | 0.28998918 |
| 23 | -0.579260657 | 0.27904191 |
| 23 | 0.189076758 | 0.26904881 |
| 23 | -0.206333307 | 0.26927626 |
| 23 | 0.127018442 | 0.26839493 |
| 23 | 0.027674431 | 0.26788267 |
| 23 | -0.092258081 | 0.26814086 |
| 23 | -0.044288205 | 0.26792252 |
| 23 | -0.142367452 | 0.26853276 |
| 23 | -0.215148812 | 0.26940011 |
| 23 | -0.014251772 | 0.26786391 |
| 33 | -0.807401429 | 0.54074357 |
| 33 | -5.766286404 | 2.57812868 |
| 33 | -0.755003347 | 0.53562688 |
| 33 | -0.720021958 | 0.53240198 |
| 33 | -0.569512001 | 0.52027149 |

The plot looks like this:

[image]

What is the correct family to indicate at this model?

yi mean is -0.5

Also: How can I make this model run since there seems not to have a way to make glmer handle negative values?

The code I am using to run this and include ID effect as a random factor is below.

res.glmer <- glmer(yi ~ 1 + (1 |ID), data=ex_dataset, family=" ")

Comment: Next time, use `dput` to embed a sample of the data that we can import in our R session. Next, I think you should just use `family = poisson(link = "identity")` maybe or `quasipoisson`?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I tried to add the data or a file with reproducible data but couldn't find how to do it. I tried to include these families in the model but none accepted negative numbers so the model still did not run. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Mossa Including data in a text table is a perfectly acceptable alternative to `dput`. `family = "poisson"` or `"quasipoisson"` makes no sense here, as `y_i` is continuous and can be < 0.

Comment: Do you have any information on how turbidity is generated? Specifically, do you have more information other than the fact that it has a mean and a standard deviation? If not, why not just use the normal distribution? What did the authors of the meta-analysis use? Which distribution is commonly used in the literature to model turbidity?

Comment: Indeed, turbidity can not be a negative value. These are not direct measures, but results from a meta-analysis I ran to assess the turbidity effect and at this step I want to know if the effect is statistically significant using mean effect size (yi). I updated the question with the code I am trying to use, without indicating family. My main problem here is that I have these negative values that are normally obtained in this kind of analysis and do not seem to be accepted in glmer.

Comment: @PatriciaNunes *"These are not direct measures"* Can you provide more details about how these turbidity numbers were calculated/standardised? Would it make sense to use the direct turbidity measures instead? Your random effect model should be able to account for a study-specific random effect directly. Lastly, is the full dataset publicly available somewhere?

Comment: @MauritsEvers These numbers are calculated by "escalc" function of metafor R package, and correspond to mean effect size on the data I gathered. I can not use direct measures because I´m interested in the effect sizes themselves. The random effect, in this case, is the id of the study, to avoid pseudoreplication. The full dataset is not published but the part I´m using in this model is complete at the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking so many questions I was interested in what a quick-and-dirty analysis of the data you provided would give. To start with a disclaimer: I am not familiar with `metafor`, nor do I know anything about meta-analyses in your area of work. With that out of the way, here's an initial analysis that may give you some food for thought.

### Plotting the data

Let's start by inspecting the data in a similar way to what you have shown in the form of a histogram. But this time we show data as a stacked histogram noting the different study identification groups as given in column `ID`. Here I assume data are stored in a tab-separated file called `"data.tsv"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- read_table2("data.tsv", col_types = "fnn")
ggplot(data, aes(yi, fill = ID)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins = 50)
```

[image]

The histogram shows some evidence for group-specific mean `yi` values, the differences of which relative to a global mean we will now try to characterise in a varying/random intercept model.

### Fitting the model

I am using the Bayesian/Stan-equivalent of `lme4::*lmer`, through the excellent `rstanarm` package (which allows you to use the usual R formula syntax). Specifically, we fit a simple varying/random intercept model with shrinkage towards a global mean, which will give a fixed effect global intercept and an ID-specific intercept *difference* (relative to the global intercept) as the random effect. This model corresponds to [Model 1 from the `rstanarm` Tutorial](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/tutorial_rstanarm.html#model-1-varying-intercept-model-with-no-predictors-variance-components-model).

```r
library(rstanarm)
fit <- stan_lmer(
    yi ~ 1 + (1 | ID), 
    data = data, 
    prior = normal(0, 1, autoscale = FALSE),
    prior_aux = student_t(3, 0, 1, autoscale = FALSE),
    adapt_delta = 0.99)
```

### Model inspection

**Pending a thorough model validation step**, we can now use the `tidybayes` package to extract posterior draws using `tidybayes::spread_draws` to calculate and plot ID-specific intercept point estimates (median and 95% quantile intervals).

```
library(tidybayes)
fit %>%
    spread_draws(`(Intercept)`, b[, group]) %>%
    mutate(
        ID = str_remove(group, "ID:"),
        a = `(Intercept)` + b) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    median_qi(a) %>%
    ggplot(aes(y = ID, colour = ID)) +
    geom_point(aes(x = a), size = 2) + 
    geom_linerange(aes(xmin = .lower, xmax = .upper), size = 1.2) + 
    labs(x = "Intercept")
```

[image]